# Can't level up after level-50 in borderlands 2 in True vault hunter mode

Tags: borderlands-2

I am currently playing the Borderlands 2 game in True vault hunter mode.
I am at 50th level. I have observed that I am no more being leveled up by killing enemies or by completing missions.

What could be the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leveling up past 50 requires the [Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack](http://www.borderlands2.com/vaulthunterpack/), which is paid DLC not included in the base game.  It's part of the first Season Pass, and part of the GOTY edition.

In addition to raising the level cap, it adds a 3rd playthrough option (Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode) but the two are independent.

You won't be able to gain any more levels until you've ponied up the cash.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question, If I install upgrade pack now, will it cause any problem in my current game, I mean will my saved game/ mission progress will retain or fade away? Sorry I can't vote up your answer, due to rep points. :( –

Comment: Note that there are two packs.  The first pack makes the level cap 61, and the second 72.