# Borderlands 2 Ultimate Vault Hunter Packs in True Vault Hunter Mode

Tags: borderlands-2

Me and a friend are playing Borderlands 2 on an XBox 360 and we're about halfway through completing True Vault Hunter Mode. Of course, we're level-capped at level 50 and the only real benefit of completing True Vault Hunter Mode is loot.

We are wondering if we need to complete True Vault Hunter Mode in order to get the Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode packs [1](http://www.borderlands2.com/vaulthunterpack/) and [2](http://www.borderlands2.com/vaulthunterpack2/index.html) installed. I can't seem to figure this out through the relevant websites or through [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179726/cant-level-up-after-level-50-in-borderlands-2-in-true-vault-hunter-mode) thread on Arqade, where the OP asks specifically whether installing the DLC packs will mess up their True Vault Hunter mode progress, yet no answer is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install them whenever you like. But in order to play UHVM, you have to beat the game on TVHM first, that's obvious. The Upgrade Pack 2 also includes the Digistruct Peak, an area where you can obtain OP levels, which is basically a level up without gaining more health or skillpoints. Even though you can play them before lvl 72, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Installing any DLC will not mess up any progress you have, even though it might add a few NPCs, weapons or similar things to the current game.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that Digistruct Peak is the greatest area in the game. ;-) And leveling to 72 is quite fast. After overpowering you won't get more health and skillpoints as you stated, but your skills will further increase (example: turret damage) and you get better weapons an much better shields which will make you stronger too (like more life).

Comment: I'm not sure if the Action Skills Damage is actually increasing. As far as i know, you only get better equip which makes you deal more dmg.

Comment: Well I'm quite sure that it will. On my Gaige the Deathtrap is titled as an LVL 80 Deathtrap after Overpowering. This should also count for my turrets. The turrets currently do still good damage on the higher OP's.

Comment: @ionic Yes, that might count for skills which "spawn" NPCs because they have a level. I'm pretty sure this doesn't apply to the other skills (like phaselock or buzz axe rampage)

Comment: Mh, didn't checked it definitely but I think the dmg numbers over the enemies also increased on turret hits. But well, not sure. :-)