# I have all DLC and I can't level up past 50

Tags: borderlands-2

For the past couple of years I've been playing Borderlands 2 on my PS3. A week ago I bought Borderlands the Handsome Collection for my PS4, and after porting my save I've found that I am not gaining exp for any kills and/or quests.

What am I missing?

(I've checked, this is not a duplicate question, [the question in which this is similar to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179726/cant-level-up-after-level-50-in-borderlands-2-in-true-vault-hunter-mode) was in a standing point of not having the DLCs)

[Handsome Pack Details](http://www.gamestop.com/ps4/games/borderlands-the-handsome-collection/120032)

It includes, among other things, both The Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack and 
Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 2.  In fact, it includes absolutely everything released for the game, even all the obscure skin packs.

Comment: Can you confirm if the Handsome Collection includes the Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack?  If not, I think it is a duplicate.

Comment: The Handsome collection DOES include all the DLC.

Comment: Have you finished the game on True Vault Hunter Mode? I haven't tested this, but a very old post on Reddit suggest you can't level past 50 until you finish TVHM, regardless of DLC.

Comment: "camelCase" yes it has DLC, search it up, easy to find... Longspeak, I will try this, thank you for your suggestion...

Answer (score 3):

I'm 99% sure The Handsome Jack Collection has True Vault Hunter Mode (being the fact I own it).  You cannot level past 50 on the first play-through.  To level past 50, you have to enter TVHM at the [Start Menu](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/True_Vault_Hunter_Mode).  Keep in mind, you have to beat the story first, then you have the opportunity to play further.

And I'd hate to be that guy, but make sure the DLCs are actually downloaded.